# Binding to property that a class

Tags: wpf, binding, properties, converters

How can I use binding without a `Converter` like the commented code below?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {ABC = new ABCClass();      
    InitializeComponent();
        //Binding binding = new Binding();
        //binding.Source = this;
        //binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ABC");
        //binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        //txtKey.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = this;
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ABC");
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    binding.Converter = new ABCTypeConverter();
    txtKey.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}
```

Class and `Converter`:

```
public ABCClass ABC { get; set; }
}


public class ABCClass
{
    public int A = 1;
    public int B = 2;
    public int C = 3;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (A + B + C).ToString();
    }
}
```

The `Converter` code was removed because the site editor does not allow "mostly code". This code does not need "mode detail".

Answer (score 1):

WPF does not support binding to fields. only [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

Change your class

```
public class ABCClass 
{
    public int A = 1;
    public int B = 2;
    public int C = 3;

    public override string ToString() 
    {
       return (A + B + C).ToString();
    }
}
```

For this:

```
public class ABCClass 
{
    public int A {get;set;}
    public int B {get;set;}
    public int C {get;set;}

    public override string ToString() 
    {
       return (A + B + C).ToString();
    }

    public ABCClass()
    {
        A = 1;
        B = 2;
        C = 3;
    }
}
```

By the way, you should be creating bindings in XAML, not procedural code.

Also, keep in mind that if you later want to modify these values of `A,B,C`, these changes will not be reflected unless you [Implement INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) adequately.

And please, get used to C# notation, putting "egyptian braces" like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    //...Etc    
}
```

instead of the CORRECT way

```
 public class MyClass
 {
      //...Etc
 }
```

Makes me want to VOMIT because of the similarity with crappy java stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the `ABCClass`'s `ToString` value to show in the `TextBox` named `txtKey`. If this is the case, you don't need a converter at all because the default behavior of a `Binding` is to use the `ToString` value when a non-string object is bound into a string property (`TextBox.Text` in this case).

Although it is not necessary to use properties for your `A,B,C` values to support this scenario, it is bad practice in general to use public fields so you should consider making them private or wrapping them with properties.